# Manual browser refreshing showing json data in webpage instead of HTML using angular JS and node js

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am using `AngularJS` `ui-Router` and `node js`.Response is coming as JSON. Normally, the page was rendered properly. If I refresh the same page manually, it displays JSON Data instead of HTML.

Kindly, help me to fix this issue.

```
angular.module('app.routes',[])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
        $locationProvider
        .html5Mode({
            enabled:true,
            requireBase:false
        })
        .hashPrefix('');    
}]) 


.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider){
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');

            $stateProvider.state('/', {
                templateUrl: '/views/login.html'
              })

.state('admin', {
                url: '/admin',
                templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
                controller: 'AdmCtrl',
                })
.state('admin1', {
                templateUrl: 'views/index1.html',
                controller: 'AdmCtrl1',
                })
```

Comment: its not clear how are you doing that.. would be better if you have shared your code

Comment: I am using angular UI-router for routing.when i click some menu, page is loading properly with UI but in the same page if i manually refresh means UI got disappearing response json is displaying in that page

Comment: while manual refreshing angular itself not calling.How to fix kindly help me

Comment: Unless we can see your `controller` and `html` code how would we know what's going wrong? If you can update your question with code we can try...

Answer (score 0):

You have turned on `html5Mode` routing.

This is a declaration that your internal angular route URLs **are the same as your server's URLs**.

In practise, it looks like you have actually configured the server to send the data as JSON instead.

---

You need to change your server side code to serve up HTML documents for those URLs instead of JSON.

Alternatively, turn off `html5Mode` and go back to [hashbangs](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).

Comment: sorry i am new to angular js , can you please suggest me what i have to change in that code

Comment: @kaviarasu — Nothing. "You need to change your **server side** code"

Comment: Sorry,in server side code i am taking value from database and sending the data as JSON format(i.e)res.json(data).is it ok or i need to change anything else in server side code

Comment: @kaviarasu — You need to change your server side code to serve up HTML documents for [the URLs you describe in your angular routes] instead of JSON.

Comment: one doubt , i can render the html page based on URl but i need dynamic data need to bind in that HTML Page , for that any reference

Comment: @kaviarasu — You need to learn whatever server side language you are using. I don't even know what language that is.